# MATLAB: Multiple occurences data in the pdist function: how?

Tags: matlab

MATLAB: we have data that give x y coordinates of occurences. Often there are more then 1 occurences on one location. This generates a problem when we want to use this data in the function pdist. We tried to change the data into a list with x y coordinates for EACH occurence, but havent managed so far. Does anyone have a solution for this?

```
% initial values m = 0;
[X,Y,People,Positive] = textread('Loaloa_data.txt', '%f%f%f%f', 'headerlines', 1); 
LoaData = [X,Y,People, Positive]; 

%calculate percentage of infected people per location 
Percentage_per_Location = (Positive(:)./People(:))*100; 

%calculate percentage of total infected people per location 
TotPos = sum(Positive); 
Percentage_of_Total = Positive(:)./TotPos*100; 
LoaData = [X,Y,People,Positive,Percentage_per_Location, Percentage_of_Total];

%Make a new frequency table in which every value of Positive has a x and y 
%value. 
% first make a new matrix with x and y coordinated and positive values. 
LengthColumn = (1:197)'; 
Matrix1 = [LengthColumn,X,Y,Positive]; 
Freq = zeros(sum(Positive(:)),2) ; 

% r = Matrix1(:,1) 
% CumFreq = ([1: sum(Positives)]); 
% Freq = Matrix1(:,4); 
% xyData =zeros(length(Freq),2); 
for i=1:length(Matrix1(:,1)) 
    %for m<=TotPos 
    F = Matrix1(i,4) 
    for j =[1:F] 
        m = m+j 
        Freq(m,1:2) = Matrix1(i,2:3) 
    end 
    % end 
end
```

Comment: can you please format your code... it is difficult to read

Comment: @Serge: Please update your question and put the code into your question.

Comment: "generates a problem" – what is the problem?

Comment: Thanx 4 u'r fast reaction, I have been busy rushing 4 "my other deadline", hence my late reaction. Since I am new here, I could not find the way to place my script here more readable. I found the solution.  Would like to place it here, but have troubles editing it to more reading, like the friendly person that edited my code above. Tips welcome. Problem is that if I press enter to put part of the code on a new line, it places the comment automaticly instead.